# Where did the popular Chanuka brachos niggun develop?

Tags: blessing, chanuka, song-poetry

What is the source for the popular niggun that is generally sung in America (and maybe elsewhere) for the brachos on lighting the Chanuka lights? How far back does this tune go? Is it an American "invention" or did it come over from Europe? Or is it the niggun that the Chashmona'im used when they lit the Menorah?

Comment: Can you link to sheet music or a recording of this tune?

Comment: "Or is it the niggun that the Chashmona'im used when they lit the Menorah?" Is this a joke? The Chasmona'im wouldn't have said "...to light Chanukkah candles" before there was a holiday named Chanukkah.

Comment: While some Jewish melodies are undoubtedly ancient (I've heard it said that the melodies used for Ps. 144 on Motza"Sh may date back to before Churban Bayit Sheini) it is doubtful, musicologically speaking, that the popular niggun (which I use only at home, I use a different one when in schul) is all that old. To me, it sounds like at the oldest, it would date to the Classical era (c. 1750-1806) at the oldest, although I suspect it's newer.

Comment: I'm assuming the tune you're referring to is track 2 [here](https://rsa.fau.edu/album/36447).

Comment: @DoubleAA. After the war, when the mitzvah to light was established.

Comment: Abraham Baer doesn't have that melody in Ba'al T'fillah, at least not for Chanukah candlelighting.  I would therefore guess that the tune is from the 20th century -- just a guess though.